# Integration in respect to a complex measure

Tags: measure-theory

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure) (Section "Integration in respect to a complex measure"), they say that:

> Another approach is to not develop a theory of integration from scratch, but rather use the already available concept of integral of a real-valued function with respect to a non-negative measure. To that end, it is a quick check that the real and imaginary parts μ1 and μ2 of a complex measure μ are finite-valued signed measures. One can apply the Hahn-Jordan decomposition to these measures to split them as
>   $$ \mu_1=\mu_1^+-\mu_1^-$$
>   and
>   $$
>     \mu_2=\mu_2^+-\mu_2^-
> $$
>   where $μ_1^+, μ_1^-, μ_2^+, μ_2^-$ are finite-valued non-negative measures (unique in some sense).

Where does the minus sign come from? What about $\mu_1^+ +\mu_1^-$?

**EDIT** 
Further they write

> Then, for a measurable function f which is real-valued for the moment, one can define
>   $$
>     \int_X \! f \, d\mu = \left(\int_X \! f \, d\mu_1^+ - \int_X \! f \, d\mu_1^-\right) + i \left(\int_X \! f \, d\mu_2^+ - \int_X \! f \, d\mu_2^-\right) \tag{1}
> $$
>   as long as the expression on the right-hand side is defined, that is, all four integrals exist and when adding them up one does not encounter the indeterminate ∞−∞.
>    Given now a complex-valued measurable function, one can integrate its real and imaginary components separately as illustrated above and define, as expected,
>   $$
>     \int_X \! f \, d\mu = \int_X \! \Re(f) \, d\mu + i \int_X \! \Im(f) \, d\mu. \tag{2} 
> $$

How does (1) related to (2)? Why doesn't something like $[d]\Re(\mu)$ or  show up?

Comment: (1) is the definition of integration of a *real valued* function with respect to the complex measure $\mu$ -- in terms of four integrals with respect to *positive measures* (which I assume is familiar to you)

(2) goes on to define integrals of *complex valued* functions with respect to the complex measured by splitting the function $f$ in its real and imaginary parts

Comment: @mf Thanks so far, but I'm not familar with positive measure. Do you have a good reference?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seemed like a natural assumption. I wouldn't recommend trying to understand complex measures without doing positive measures first. There are several dozen if not hundreds of decent textbooks in measure theory and integration theory. Not sure I can single out one in particular. You might look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71418/seeking-a-laymans-guide-to-measure-theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps an example may help.  Consider the complex measure $d\mu = (\cos(x)+ i \sin(x))\ dx$ on $[0,2\pi]$.  The real part is $d\mu_1 = \cos(x)\ dx$ and the imaginary part is $d\mu_2 = \sin(x)\ dx$.  We then split up the real part as $d\mu_1 = d\mu_1^+ - d\mu_1^-$ where
$d\mu_1^+ = \rho_1^+(x)\ dx$, $d\mu_1^- = \rho_1^-(x)\ dx$, $\rho_1^+(x) = \max(\cos(x),0)$ and $\rho_1^-(x) = -\min(\cos(x),0)$.  Similarly $d\mu_2 = d\mu_2^+ - d\mu_2^-$.  Note that
$d\mu_1^+$, $d\mu_1^-$, $d\mu_2^+$ and $d\mu_2^-$ are all positive measures (the whole point of this exercise being that we already know how to integrate with a positive measure, so this construction lets us define integration with a complex measure in terms of integrations with positive measures). That is, $\int_X f\ d\mu$ is defined to be
$\int_X f\ d\mu_1^+ - \int_X f\ d\mu_1^- + i \int_X f \ d\mu_2^+ - i \int_X f \ d\mu_2^-$.

Actually we know how to integrate *real-valued* functions with a positive measure, but what about complex-values functions?  That's what (2) is about.  If $F$ is a complex-valued function, you split it up into its real and imaginary parts, say $F = g + i h$ where $g$ and $h$ are real, and then $\int_X F \ d\mu = \int_X g \ d\mu + i \int_X h \ d\mu$.
And we just saw in the last paragraph how to integrate the real-valued functions $g$ and $h$ with the complex measure $\mu$, so we're done.

Comment: +1 for very helpful example. You should put it there or link your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hahn decomposition, the usual way is to split the measure into two *positive* measures, hence the minus sign. In other words, $\mu^-$ is not the negative part of $\mu$, but "minus the negative part".

See [Wikipedia: Hahn decomposition theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem)

Comment: Thanks so far, but I still don't understand that Wiki page. Is this a typo in there?

Comment: Where is the typo?

Comment: "Nowhere, everythings fine" is also an accepted answer (to my comment).

Comment: Ok, it sounded like you had something particular in mind. I couldn't find any glaringly obvious typos.