# Book Suggestions for an Introduction to Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

Couldn't find this question asked anywhere on the site, so here it is! Do you guys have any recommendations for someone being introduced to measure theory and lebesgue integrals?

A mentor has suggested a book that's in french, but unfortunately I don't know french (heck I barely know english) - so english books only please!

Thanks in advanced!

EDIT: Did not realize this had been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71418/seeking-a-laymans-guide-to-measure-theory) but I'm going to leave this question open to see if there are any newer books (that question was originally asked in 2011). If I am doing something wrong here, just give me a *gentle* shoutout in the comments and I'll be understanding and close this

Comment: Similar discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71418/seeking-a-laymans-guide-to-measure-theory)

Comment: @Stahl did not see that at first! thank you very much, I have decided to leave this on open to see if there are any newer suggestions

Comment: (just so you know, it's still 2013)

Comment: the question was originally asked in 2011

Comment: Right, I'm only saying because you said it was "asked in 2013" in the edit of your question, and you linked to your own question :) (I fixed it up for you)

Comment: I am voting to close as a duplicate, since this was asked [many](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46213/) [times](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36147/) [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71418/) and I don't quite see the point in collecting the same list of books an $n$-th time. If an earth-shattering new book on measure theory has appeared in the last two years, my apologies.

Comment: @Stahl ah ok thank you

Comment: @Martin ok no problem, thank you

Comment: You can find many of those threads in the "Linked" and "Related" questions in the right hand column on this page.

Comment: @Martin accidentally double clicked the upvote, sorry I took it away D:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Schillings [*Measures, Integrals, and Martingales*](http://books.google.com/books?id=_OjSIphIrH0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false).

It's a great introductory text for Measure Theory, gentle, but rigorous. The author's website has solutions to the book, as well as Errata, etc. You can take a look at the table of contents in the link given above.

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate this!

Comment: @amWhy: excellent suggestion and OP's love when they can get at answers! +1

Comment: Thanks, Amzoti! A trend towards making these sorts of posts CW today/lately...it goes back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

I would say Fremlin: Measure theory is a good choice (i guess it's freely available on the web).
The best measure theory book i know is unfortunately in German (Elstrodt: Maß- und Integrationstheorie)

Hope your happy with Fremlin!

Comment: I appreciate the advice! I will be looking into both books!

Answer (score 2):

I recomend [An introduction to measure theory](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf)  by 
[Terence Tao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Tao) ( Fields Medalist  in 2006).

Comment: Are the answers to exercises available somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Frank Jone's Lebesgue Measure on Euclidean space is the greatest math book that I have ever read. It gives a very slow introduction to lebesgue measure. It is fabulous; I did every homework problem for fun.