# Does every random variable(continous) has a probability density function?

Tags: random-variables

what is the criterion for a random variable(continous) for existence of probability density function for it? Could you provide some cases of random variable(continous) where pdf ceases to exist.

Comment: A (real-valued) random variable $X$ has density $f$ if you can write $$P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy$$. For a random variable which does not admit a density, take any discrete random variable - geometric, bernoulli, etc.

Comment: How are you defining a continuous random variable?

Comment: Sometimes "continuous random variable" means "random variable with a density function."

Comment: a continous random variable has continous CDF function.

Comment: It happens if the cdf is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_continuous).

Comment: Could you explain to me what is the difference between absolutely continous and just continous?

Comment: An example in which it is not absolutely continuous is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution

Comment: @VineelVeludandi You'll understand it better if you follow the link that André gave.

Comment: oh could you suggest me some book on Measure theory that is simple enough to understand who is from electrcial engineering background.

Comment: @VineelVeludandi Are you comfortable with real analysis? That would really be a prerequisite for a smooth study of measure theory. Take a look at
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393972/book-suggestions-for-an-introduction-to-measure-theory and
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46213/reference-book-on-measure-theory