# Any elementary-level text or notes on (i) measure theory? (ii) Lebesgue integration?

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I still have no background in measure theory or Lebesgue integration. So is there any elementary-level resource --- book, set of notes, tutorial paper, website, or online video lecture series --- which I can use for getting some knowledge of these fields?

Comment: Define "elementary level", please!

Comment: Terence Tao's book Analysis II gives a good, relatively short introduction to measure theory and Lebesgue integration.  After Tao's book, I recommend checking out [Wheeden and Zygmund](https://www.amazon.com/Measure-Integral-Introduction-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0824764994), or perhaps [Stein and Shakarchi](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Integration-Princeton-Lectures/dp/0691113866/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=PTFF1RF364XFXTBB3J7M).

Comment: I found the part of Folland's "Real Analysis" dealing with measure theory and the Lebesgue integral explained concisely and clearly. I also personally enjoyed reading Billingsley's "Probability and Measure", but you have to beware that there is a lot of information in that book, and that it is big. You could maybe consult Folland's book first, and then, if you have some  time and want to know more, consult Billingsley's book.

Comment: @user436658 by "elementary-level" I mean a book suitable for not-very-mathematically-mature undergraduate-level students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111101005/) is an introductory video course on measure and integration by Prof.Inder Rana of IIT Bombay. There are total 40 lectures with each one almost of an hour. Also he uses his own book on measure and integration along with Paul Halmos's and Royden's as mentioned in @BAYMAX's answer.

The syllabus of the course as well as the references are mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest three books which helped me-

1) *Royden's  Real  Analysis*,here in this it gives motivation towards the topic as well as illustrative text,nice examples,excercises.

2)*Measure Theory and Integration by G. de Barra.*

3)*Paul Halmos,Measure theory*.

Also there are some similar questions asked and may contain some references as per your requirement -  [Reference book on measure theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46213/reference-book-on-measure-theory?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393972/book-suggestions-for-an-introduction-to-measure-theory?rq=1).

And some online notes [here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4225/2011/fremlin-mt1.pdf) and [here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4225/2011/fremlin-vol2.pdf).

Hope this helps!