# Books on measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can someone kindly suggested a good book on measure theory? Taking into consideration a good treatment of the abstract measures and Caratheodory approach.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46213/reference-book-on-measure-theory?rq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71418/seeking-a-laymans-guide-to-measure-theory?rq=1), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393972/book-suggestions-for-an-introduction-to-measure-theory?rq=1).

Comment: Here are a couple of books I don't think have been mentioned: [**Measure Theory and Integration**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0821841807) by Michael E. Taylor (2006) is very readable and it touches on a lot of supplementary topics of importance in contemporary research. [**Measure Theory and Integration**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0824754018) by M. M. Rao (2nd edition, 2004) is one place to go if you want to jump in the deep end of the pool right away.

Comment: @Dave thanks a lot i just checked the book by Micheal Taylor.. Seems very helps.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications (Pure and Applied Mathematics: A Wiley Series of Texts, Monographs and Tracts) [Hardcover]
Gerald B. Folland (Author)

[http://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Techniques-Applications-Mathematics/dp/0471317160](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Elstrodt's "Maß- und Integrationstheorie" a lot, and believe it to be an excellent introduction to the topic. The book is german, though - I don't know if there's an english translation.

Answer (score 0):

I really found Tao's book *An Introduction to Measure Theory* really quite excellent. It provides a lot of motivation as well as a lot of foundation to the theory of measure. Most books just start talking about $\sigma$-algebras without really explaining the motivation, etc. With Tao's book he works up the development of the Lebesgue integral on  $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then gradually moves to the parallel development of Lebesgue integral on abstract measure spaces, using $\sigma$-algebra. This is a really effective treatment because the reader understands the relationship between borel sets on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the sets in a $\sigma$-algebra.